# Js Regex only allowed characters one occurence

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Trying the regex very hard but could not get the desired result.

1. Must begin with numbers and maximum of 4
2. followed by only one allowed alphabet

Please have a look at below code.

```js
var strings = [
 '1h', //should match
 '13s', //should match
 '30m', //should match
 '42hr', //should not match
 '8   hours  ', //should not match
 '765765', //should not match
 '5sec', //should not match
 '23445345345s', //should not match
 '335m' //should match
];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) 
{
    var match = strings[i].match(/\d{4}[h|m|s]{1}/g);
  console.log(strings[i], (match ? "Match" : "Not match"));
}
```

Comment: "Must begin with numbers and maximum of 4": then you want `{1,4}`, not just `{4}`. For a character group, you don't use `|`, so `[hms]`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton tried it. 5sec and 23445345345s should not be matched. but it is getting matched.

Comment: Oops, I meant please see https://regex101.com/r/lMlyFS/1 to see that `/^[0-9]{1,4}[hms]$/gm` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex should be:

```
/^\d{1,4}[hms]$/gm
```

First, you require 4 digits with `d{4}`

Change it to `d{1,4}` to be one to four digits

Then add a `$` to indicate the end of the string, so it doesn't allow more characters after the letter

Check out [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), Really useful for testing and understanding regex

Comment: hey 23445345345s is getting matched

Comment: Forgot ^ at the start, fixed it

Comment: Using a character class to match either h m s does not need a pipe char. The pattern can be written as `^\d{1,4}[hms]$`

Answer (score 1):

I've added a ^ to match from start

```
strings.filter(x =>  x.match(/^\d{1,4}[hms](?!\w)/g)  )
```